# How to setting pop3 for mailgun. Kentico

Tags: kentico, mailgun

I use smtp mailgun for sending email in Kentico. how i can set up pop3 for check Bounced emails from mailgun. What is a port I should use?

Comment: I'd suggest going to MailGun's support pages and ask this question.  Doesn't look like MailGun has Pop3 support any longer.  https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faq-mailbox-eol.html

Answer (score 1):

As per Brenden's comment, [MailGun are discontinuing POP3 support](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faq-mailbox-eol.html#discontinuing-pop3-imap-mailboxes).  In order to do this, you're going to need to find an alternative email supplier that supports POP3 (the linked article suggests Rackspace for example).

POP3 server listens usually listen on port 110. If you move to POP3S (using Transport Layer Security (TLS) or Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)), then you might use something like port 995.  Your mail provider's support team will be able to advise you on which port to use.